# Reading in data from text file into a VBA array

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub read_in_data_from_txt_file()

Dim dataArray() As String
Dim i As Integer

Const strFileName As String = "Z:\sample_text.txt"
Open strFileName For Input As #1

' -------- read from txt file to dataArrayay -------- '

i = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    ReDim Preserve dataArray(i)
    Line Input #1, dataArray(i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #1

Debug.Print UBound(dataArray())

End Sub
```

I'm trying to read in text line by line (assume 'sample.txt' is a regular ascii file) from a file and assign this data to consecutive elements in an array.

When I run this, I get all my data in the first value of the array.

For example, if 'sample.txt' is:

```
foo
bar
...
dog
cat
```

I want each one of these words in a consecutive array element.

Comment: Ok, read [**this**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/). You may want to `.readLine` and then `Split(.readLine, " ")`

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. What does the line `Debug.Print UBound(dataArray())` give you?

Comment: You're opening for `Input`. Have you tried opening for `Output`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is fine; if everything ends up in `dataArray(0)` then the lines in the file are not using a `CrLf` delimiter so `line input` is grabbing everything.

Instead;

```
open strFileName for Input as #1
dataArray = split(input$(LOF(1), #1), vbLf)
close #1
```

Assuming the delimiter is `VbLf` (what it would be coming from a *nix system)

Comment: Would using the vbLf constant work for Linux/Unix, Mac and Windows OSes? So if I have a text file that has

Item1
Item2
Item3

Regardless of which OS created the file it would be able to be read into an array

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean code on how to use for each loop in VBA

```
Function TxtParse(ByVal FileName As String) As String
    Dim fs, ts As Object
    Dim strdic() As String
    Dim oitem As Variant
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1, False, -2)

    strdic = Split(ts.ReadAll, vbLf)

    For Each oitem In strdic
        If InStr(oitem, "YourString") <> 0 Then
        Else
            If InStr(1, oitem, vbTab) <> 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "Line number is : "; "'" & Replace(oitem, vbTab, "','") & "'"
            Else
                    Debug.Print "Line number is : "; "'" & Replace(oitem, ",", "','") & "'"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```